# Android - Changing Gradle.properties according to flavor

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, build.gradle

I'm building an Android app with React Native and I have troubles configuring some of my API key.

I have one of my API key in my `Gradle.properties`

```
RNGP_ANDROID_API_KEY=mysupersecretkey
```

And I have two different flavor: beta for testing and prod for production.
I would like to override the `RNGP_ANDROID_API_KEY` in my two flavors
Like this:

```
flavorDimensions 'env'
productFlavors {
    beta {
        dimension 'env'
        applicationId "com.fake.package"
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        manifestPlaceholders=[google_api:"beta_key"]
    }
    prod {
        dimension 'env'
        applicationId "com.fake.package"
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        manifestPlaceholders=[google_api:"prod_key"]
    }
}
```

It works well to override value in the manifest but I don't know how to change the `Gradle.properties` value.

Please let me know what I can do!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of writing in `Gradle.properties`

Try to use it as below,

```
flavorDimensions 'env'
productFlavors {
    beta {
        dimension 'env'
        applicationId "com.fake.package"
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        manifestPlaceholders=[google_api:"beta_key"]
        buildConfigField 'String', 'RNGP_ANDROID_API_KEY', '"mysupersecretkey"'
    }
    prod {
        dimension 'env'
        applicationId "com.fake.package"
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        manifestPlaceholders=[google_api:"prod_key"]
        buildConfigField 'String', 'RNGP_ANDROID_API_KEY', '"mysupersecretkey"'
    }
}
```

You can access this variable by `BuildConfig.RNGP_ANDROID_API_KEY`

Comment: Hello, when I write 'RNGP_ANDROID_API_KEY=BuildConfig.RNGP_ANDROID_API_KEY' in my Gradle.properties, it is not recognised as a variable

Comment: you cant write BuildConfig.RNGP_ANDROID_API_KEY in Gradle.properties u need to mentioned this wherever you are using RNGP_ANDROID_API_KEY directly

Comment: buildConfigField don't change the gradleResValues.xml，the code read by R.string.xxx